# Maven: Changing remote directory structure

Tags: maven, deployment

I have just started to learn maven a few weeks ago. Currently trying to achieve the structure in my mind. Everything up to know is perfect but, i am having an issue about deploying.

The issue is:

when i perform `mvn release:perform` artifacts are being deployed to my ftp server in `ftp://centos-release/maven/linuxapp/releases/com/gmail/baturman/linuxapp/linuxapp/0.0.5/` path.

and when i perform `mvn deploy` current snapshot is being deployed to ftp server in `ftp://centos-gitlab/maven/linuxapp/snapshots/com/gmail/baturman/linuxapp/linuxapp/0.0.6-SNAPSHOT/`

everything is cool but, this is not the structure that i want. What i want to have this directory structure:

For release: `ftp://centos-release/maven/linuxapp/releases/0.0.5/`

For snapshots: `ftp://centos-release/maven/linuxapp/snapshots/0.0.6-SNAPSHOT/`

Could you please advise?

Here is my pom file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.gmail.baturman.linuxapp</groupId>
<artifactId>linuxapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
<description>Linux App - Powered by git and maven :)</description>
<name>Linux App</name>

<!-- PROPERTIES -->
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<!-- RELEASE INFORMATION -->
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:gitlab@centos-gitlab:maven/linuxapp.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:gitlab@centos-gitlab:maven/linuxapp.git</developerConnection>
    <url>http://centos-gitlab/maven/linuxapp</url>
    <tag>v0.0.3</tag>
</scm>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>release-server</id>
        <name>Release Repository</name>
        <url>ftp://centos-gitlab/maven/${project.artifactId}/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>release-server</id>
        <name>Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>ftp://centos-gitlab/maven/${project.artifactId}/snapshots</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>



<!-- BUILD -->
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <!-- EXTENSIONS -->
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>

    <!-- RESOURCES -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/conf</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <!-- PLUGINS -->
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                <useJvmChmod>true</useJvmChmod>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>release-server</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why do you need it deployed that way?  It matches the `groupId` that you defined in your pom.xml, i.e. what you are telling it to do. What will you achieve by deploying it that way, i.e. do you have an existing script / app (that doesn't use Maven dependency resolution libraries) that needs it deployed "your" way?

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, the FTP server i am deploying is not intended to use as maven repository. It's like publishing all stuffs in internal network.

Comment: In that case, you need to create a custom plugin or Maven ant-run task that copies the artifacts to the directory format of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

First i would suggest to start using a repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/) which is a better solution than an ftp server. Apart from that you have to change your definitions:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>release-server</id>
        <name>Release Repository</name>
        <url>ftp://centos-gitlab/maven/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>release-server</id>
        <name>Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>ftp://centos-gitlab/maven/snapshots/</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but as i stated in my comment, i want to use this FTP server for publishing all contents (artifacts, docs etc) for internal usage.

Comment: Using a repository does not prevent publishing all content for internal usage. I don't see any advantage of a FTP server over a Repository server which can be accessed via simple http.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. At first i was thinking that repository managers are online services, but apparently it seems, i can install Archiva on my server. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @khmarbaise, maybe you can share a tutorial on how to publish a dependency to one of these repository managers?